# Everything crashes when I use "bundle exec"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler, rake-task

I'm making a gem, and I added a Gemfile to my repository. When I run

```
$ rake test
```

Everything goes fine. The `test` command I wrote myself, and it just executes all the tests in my test folder. So, something like this

```
ruby -Ilib *_test.rb
```

But, when I prefix the `rake test` command with `bundle exec`, I start getting errors from the only gem I use, `faraday`. Do you know what could be the problem? (I'm using rbenv)

All of the errors are of this kind:

```
Flickrie::Error: Flickrie::Error
/Users/jstojanovski/Projects/flickrie/lib/flickrie/client.rb:37:in `on_complete'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in `block in call'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/response.rb:62:in `on_complete'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/request/json.rb:32:in `call'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/connection.rb:210:in `run_request'
/Users/jstojanovski/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.6/lib/faraday/connection.rb:93:in `get'
/Users/jstojanovski/Projects/flickrie/lib/flickrie/client.rb:44:in `get'
/Users/jstojanovski/Projects/flickrie/lib/flickrie/client.rb:85:in `get_licenses'
/Users/jstojanovski/Projects/flickrie/lib/flickrie.rb:72:in `get_licenses'
/Users/jstojanovski/Projects/flickrie/test/license_test.rb:22:in `test_get_licenses'
```

Here `Flickrie::Error` is just something I raise whenever an exception is raised during a GET request (I'm making GET requests on the Flickr API).

These errors also occur when I'm running the normal `rake test` with different ruby versions (different from 1.9.3).

Comment: **What** errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to add `activesupport` to the Gemfile, because `faraday` uses it without telling you. On older versions of ruby you need to use the `~> 2.3.8` version. This is just a development dependency.